# I use 500+ images, folder size is too large. how can I decrease

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I use 500+ images in my application. And I will use more. I downloaded png images.
I made it as small as I could but folder size is too large. When I get the apk, will the size decrease or should I do something now? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use more images but less space used try get images from network like upload them to google photos or other then just get the link in place of image it will make you able to use more images with less storage or you can use firebase storage also to store images.

Comment: thanks :) i'll try firebase

Comment: @cs23 You should definitely try it XD

Comment: Please you must see my question if you have answer for it then please must tell here is the link for question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64619174/how-to-check-if-user-is-new-or-existing-when-login-with-google-using-firebase-in)